# Finding all digits that may be followed by a decimal point

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to findall combinations of of a digit followed by decimal point and another digit. The last final decimal point may be missing

```
E.g., 
1.3.3 --> Here there are two combinations 1.3 and 3.3
1.3.3. --> Here there are two combinations 1.3 and 3.3
```

However, when I run the following code?

```
st='1.2.3 The Mismatch of Accommodation and Disparity and the Depths of Focus and of Field'
import re
re.findall('\d\.\d+',st)
['1.2']
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `re.findall('\d\.\d*',st)` `+` requires at least a right-hand digit, which you don't have in the last example. also, consuming the digit makes that the next doesn't match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may match 1+ digits in the consuming pattern and *capture* the fractional part inside a positive lookahead, then join the groups:

```
import re
st='1.2.3 The Mismatch of Accommodation and Disparity and the Depths of Focus and of Field'
print(["{}{}".format(x,y) for x,y in re.findall(r'(\d+)(?=(\.\d+))',st)])
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/r4uhpK) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DTJRZ3/1).

**Regex details**:

- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `(?=(\.\d+))` - a positive lookahead that requires the presence of:

  - `(\.\d+)` - Group 2: a dot and then 1+ digits

Answer (score 3):

Because you can't match the same characters twice, you need to put a capture group inside a lookahead assertion to not consume digits that are on the right of the dot:

```
re.findall(r'(?=(\d+\.\d+))\d+\.', st)
```